# Installing new fonts in Firefox OS device

Tags: fonts, adb, firefox-os

I need to install Sinhala fonts in a Firefox OS device. It is a Intex Cloud FX device (Platform Version: 28.1).  Here is a screenshot of my settings display:

[image]

I tried some `adb` commands to push the fonts to my phone, but it says

> Read-only file system

This is the result I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use "adb remount" ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, :) I tried it also. But it failed. Any other way to install sinhala fonts in firefox browser?